# What happens to in-flight AJAX requests inside an iframe if the iframe is removed from the DOM

Tags: ajax, iframe

So a little bit of background might be useful. I have a small javascript snippet that runs on third party sites that when the end user clicks a button loads and iframe onto the page. Inside this iframe users can fill out a form that submits an AJAX request to a webserver of mine.

After the user submits the form they can close the iframe visibly and I remove the iframe element from the DOM on the third party site. What happens to in-flight AJAX requests inside the iframe if it is removed from the DOM on the third party site? Do they complete?

If people are unsure could people suggest possible ways of reliably testing this.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think ajax is just a request + function to run hooked to be executed after the response comes. What will probably happen is that the javascript function will be executed and will just log an error in the browser.